# WTForm always return False

Tags: python, json, validation, wtforms

I'm using **WTForms** for my `json validation`:

**forms.py**

```
class vcodeForm(Form):
type = TextField('type', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/vcode', methods = ['GET'])  
def vcode():
    form = vcodeForm(request.args)
    return str(form.validate())
```

**args(using httpie tool)**

```
http --session=s1 GET localhost:5000/vcode type==register
```

The value returned is always `Flase`, I print the value of `form.type.data`

```
<input id="type" name="type" type="text" value="register">
```

Where did i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using [json validation](https://gist.github.com/corbinbs/3791168)

It's great and very easy to understand.